# jQuery js no conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress website and with the new 4.5 update (which I believe wordpress has updated their jQuery libraries) it is causing a custom.js file I used previously, to be ignored.

I believe from research that adding a no conflict may fix this issue (I could be wrong but I cannot think of any other solution).

I have included the content of my custom.js file in this post and I was just wondering how I add the no conflict code and if I have to include any code in my header.php or anywhere else? Thanks in advance!

```js
// JavaScript Document

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu-primary > #menu-primary-items > .menu-item-1627 a").click(function() {
      if (!$(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").length && !$(this).parent().hasClass("current_page_item") && $(window).width() <= 5024) {
        window.location.replace($(this).attr("href"));
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu-primary > #menu-primary-items > .menu-item-1627 a").click(function() {
      if (!$(this).parent().find("#menu-primary").length && !$(this).parent().hasClass("current_page_item") && $(window).width() <= 5024) {
        window.location.replace($(this).attr("href"));
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);

// ADVANCED

if (document.URL.indexOf("http://url.com/contact/") >= 0) {
  (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#menu-primary > #menu-primary-items > .menu-item a").click(function() {
        if (!$(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").length && !$(this).parent().hasClass("current_page_item") && $(window).width() <= 5024) {
          window.location.replace($(this).attr("href"));
        }
      });
    });
  })(jQuery);
}

if (document.URL.indexOf("http://url.com/contact/") >= 0) {
  (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#menu-primary > #menu-primary-items > .menu-item a").click(function() {
        if (!$(this).parent().find("#menu-primary").length && !$(this).parent().hasClass("current_page_item") && $(window).width() <= 5024) {
          window.location.replace($(this).attr("href"));
        }
      });
    });
  })(jQuery);
}
```

Comment: Documentation is always a good place to start: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: what is in `custom.js`?

Comment: Hi Techie_28, that code above is all that is in custom.js. And I have called that js file in the functions.php. Worked in previous versions of WordPress but since the update it is not working at all

Comment: I never need to run a no conflict if I use `jQuery` instead of `$`.. where is your code for noConflict mode?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question, sorry?

Comment: have you used this `jQuery.noConflict();` kind of statement anywhere?

Comment: No. I had never heard of it before today. This JS script stops the 'double-tap' on links on mobile touch devices. It all worked fine until I updated wordpress yesterday and now its like wordpress is totally ignoring it. I'm not even 100% sure if no conflict will fix it but its the only thing I can think of seen as though wordpress updated its JS libraries

Comment: try replacing the `$` sign's in this file with `jQuery`

Comment: This hasn't worked. It is definitely something to do with WordPress js libraries and I know that because I have just replaced the /wp-admin/js and /wp-includes/js folders with the previous version (4.4) and my website started functioning correctly again

Answer (score 0):

you can add this following line on top of the js.

And your problem will solve 
and you can use $ sign any where in js

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this hasn't worked. The javascript is still being 'ignored'. Do I need to add any other code anywhere else?

Comment: then use (function($) { })(jQuery) only one time in whole js add do your code in this function don`t use it multiple time one file

Comment: I don't think I understand this instruction?

Comment: what do you mean "ignored"?Does your browser console show any error?

Comment: Well it's like it is ignoring it because it worked before and now it doesn't. I have just found these errors in Inspect Element:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.0
jquery.js?ver=1.12.3:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: area[href*=#],a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not([href^='#tab']):not([href^='#quicktab']):not([href^='#pane'])
util.js:220 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys